# Python: Binarize image and fill shapes

Tags: python, image, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to measure the similarity between two images [[a](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/5613309c178f758c417fe3c561f6e856/raw/8efb43c08feea04c9aeb8c8fe75a55858cc9485c/a.jpg), [b]](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/5613309c178f758c417fe3c561f6e856/raw/8efb43c08feea04c9aeb8c8fe75a55858cc9485c/b.jpg), one of which is totally underexposed:

[image]

I thought I could binarize the second image to make it appear more visually similar to the first, but it seems the second image doesn't have much intensity at all in the leafs, as the following binarization code leaves the images basically unchanged:

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave
from skimage.transform import resize
from glob import glob

size = 255
a = imread('a.jpg', mode='L')
b = imread('b.jpg', mode='L')
a = resize(a, (size, size))
b = resize(b, (size, size))

# specify a threshold 0-1
threshold = 0.8

# make all pixels < threshold black
a_binarized = 255.0 * (a > threshold)
b_binarized = 255.0 * (b > threshold)

imsave('a_binarized.jpg', a)
imsave('b_binarized.jpg', b)
```

Does anyone know how I can manipulate the second image to make it look like the first? Any help others can offer on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The right image is already almost black-and-white. (Or grayscale with a very sharp bi-modal distribution.) That's why binarization does not make it any different. Try extracting contours from the left image?

Comment: @DYZ, yes, exactly. Is there a technique that will allow one to transform the image on the right into something resembling the one on the left? I have thousands of such pairs...

Comment: And if you use a high-pass filter to get only the edges of the images and then calculate their similarity?

Answer (score 0):

Use a high pass filter to get contours of the images and after compare them. You can, for example, use the sobel filter:

```
    from scipy import ndimage, misc
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

    image1 = ndimage.sobel(image1) 
    image2 = ndimage.sobel(image2)

    print(mean_squared_error(image1, image2)) # difference between them
```

This works because the higher frequencies are in the image edges, so by applying a high pass filter, you keep those high frequencies and attenuates the lowest. As the images have the same borders, you will be able to compare them and get a high similarity (or a low mean squared error)

Comment: thanks for your thought. The only catch is the MSE is lower between A and a random cat image than the MSE between the two images above :/